# Can we connect Android mobile with Type-c to DB9 serial port ?, if, through that can we communicate with React Native app for receive and send data

Tags: react-native, serial-port, mobile-application, usbserial

I am trying to connect android mobile with Type-c to a serial port DB9. Through this i want to communicate with a smart current meter that we use to have i our households. I want to get the data from the smart meter to the mobile and vice versa, can i ??. I have planed to use React Native for building the mobile application. Is there any suggestion. Thank You.

I have a USB2.0 or USB3.0 to DB9 serial port connector i have used a type-c converter to connect with the android mobile but its not detecting is there anything i need to do ?